# Errors when creating unlocked package version with Apex Territory2 dependencies

Tags: apex, territory-management, unlocked-package, territory

Creating an unlocked package version:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p MyPackage --apiversion 48.0 -d force-app -x --wait 10
```

with classes that depent on Territory2 objects returns the following error(s) for every class that uses an object from the Territory2 "family":

> MyClassTest: Variable does not exist: territories,MyClass: Invalid type: Territory2Model

The classes compile, test and run fine on a scratch org with Enterprise Territory Management enabled.

Here is my sfdx-project.json:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "package": "MyPackage",
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "48.0",
  "packageAliases": {
    "IgusREngine": "0Hoxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

I found this here regarding unlocked package support and Territory2:
[Salesforce Spring ’20 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_api_meta.htm)

> BEHAVIOR CHANGE: For unlocked packaging, the Territory2 type now requires packages without a namespace in all API versions
>   Territory2 depends on Territory2Type, which requires packages without a namespace. This change makes the behavior of Territory2 and Territory2Type consistent, so you can now use Territory2 in unlocked packages.

It looks like it is supported, just not with a namespace and we don't use one. The related DevHub also has Enterprise Territory Management enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify this dependency in a configuration file. The file would look like this:

```
{
  "orgName": "Sample Org",
  "edition": "developer",
  "settings": {
    "territory2Settings": {
      "enableTerritoryManagement2": true
    }
  }
}
```

It must be specified as part of your sfdx-project.json, or specified on the command-line. I recommend putting it in the project file:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    { 
      "default": true,
      "definitionFile": "configs/default-config.json",
      "package": "package-name",
      "path": "force-app/package-name",
      "versionName": "ver 1.0 (hopefully)",
      "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT"
    }, ...
  ], ...
}
```

You can check all the available metadata types in the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/48), as well as sample definition files for each metadata you would like to package.

Comment: I pointed it to my scratch org def with enableTerritoryManagement2 = true and it worked, thanks! Is it actually building with that environment or why is that necessary? I always though it builds with the settings of the dev hub.

Comment: @Frank A package needs to know all of its dependencies. On installation, those dependencies are verified before moving forward. This ensures that the package will install successfully once verification completes.